# Is there any shortcut to I select the entire text in Dragon NaturallySpeaking's Advanced Scripting editor?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, naturallyspeaking

I would like to select the the entire text in Dragon's Advanced Scripting editor. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> doesn't work. Is there any shortcut to do it?

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional on Windows 7 x64 SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Franck, your approach is somewhat cumbersome. Here is a shorter solution that does all you want with two simple shortcuts.

```
Sub Main
    ' generalized solution for selecting the entire contents of a text or text box when Ctrl-A does not work
    SendKeys "^{home}", True 'to go to the beginning of the document, press Ctrl-Home
    SendKeys "^+{end}", True 'to select everything, press Ctrl-Shift-End
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great! I had forgotten to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any such shortcut. I simply hold <kbd>Page UP</kbd> for a while to place the mouse cursor at the beginning of the box, then hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Page DOWN</kbd> till it reaches the end.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl+Home/End goes to the Start/End of document. Using the hotkeys go to the start first, then hold down shift, then go to the end.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts for more hotkeys you might find useful and never knew about.